# How to verify mocked method not called with any combination of parameters using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

How can I verify that a mocked method was not called at all - with any combination of parameters - using Mockito?

For example I have an object - `myObject` - that is using a second, mocked object - `myMockedOtherObject` - that has a method - `someMethodOrOther(String parameter1, String parameter2)`.

I want to call `myObject.myMethod()` and verify that `someMethodOrOther()` *doesn't* get called - with *any* combination of parameters.

e.g.:

```
myObject.doSomeStuff();

verify(myMockedOtherObject, never()).someMethodOrOther();
```

Except I can't do that, because `someMethodOrOther()` requires specific parameters to be supplied.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want with Mockito's argument matchers:

```
myObject.doSomeStuff();

verify(myMockedOtherObject, never()).someMethodOrOther(
    Mockito.anyString(),
    Mockito.anyString()
);
```

You can make that a little less verbose with a static import like you have for `verify` and `never`.

Comment: OP: `never()` for a specific method call is the best way to ensure the method was not called. If you have verified all other method calls, or have no other method calls, you also have `verifyNoMoreInteractions(...)` and `verifyZeroInteractions(...)` at your disposal; those can make your tests more brittle than you want, though, so they aren't as good as Matt's solution.

Comment: I realize how old this answer is, but I can't seem to be able to find `never()`. However, `times(0)` seems to be available.

Comment: http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.19.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4

Answer (score 22):

You need to use argument matchers to do stuff like this.  You supply an argument matcher to correspond to every parameter in your method, but you must make sure that you pick one that has the right type.  All of the ones you are likely to need are listed at http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html.

Suppose your method is

```
public void myMethod(
    String text, int count, MyClass something, List<MyClass> someList) {
    // ...
}
```

Your verify statement might look like this.

```
verify(myMock, never()).myMethod(
    anyString(), anyInt(), any(MyClass.class), anyListOf(MyClass.class));
```

Some of the matchers that you're likely to need are -

- `anyInt(), anyLong(), anyShort(), anyBoolean(), anyByte(), anyChar(), anyFloat(), anyDouble()` - These match either the primitive version or the object version of each of these types.  In my example, I've used `anyInt()` to match an `int`, but it will also match an `Integer`.
- `any(XXX.class)` - This will match any object type at all.  In my example, I've used it to match a `MyClass`.
- `anyString()` - This is an alternative way of writing `any(String.class)`
- `anyListOf(XXX.class), anySetOf(XXX.class), anyMapOf(XXX.class, XXX.class)` - These are good for matching the standard generic collection types.  In my example, I've used `anyListOf` to match the `List<MyClass>`.

There are a handful of others, and I strongly recommend having a brief skim through the Javadoc.  But these are the ones that you are most likely to use with `never()`.

Comment: Worth mentioning there's also an `any()` which you can use for objects instead of having to type the class.

Answer (score 1):

**More Clear way of presenting the solution**

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;

//Testing scenario

verify(mockObject, never()).someMethod(mockParam1, MockParam2);
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  OP asked how to verify that the method is never called for _any_ combination of parameters, not just for two particular values.